# Using functools.partial with partial arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, functools

Trying something out with partial, I observed the following behaviour:

First, I defined a function `foo` which takes 2 non-keyword arguments:

```
>>> def foo(salutation, name):
...     print(salutation, name)
```

Then, I use partial to create a higher order wrapper.

```
>>> from functools import partial 
>>> f = partial(foo, name='Coldspeed')
```

Then, called it like this:

```
>>> f('Hey')
```

This gave me `Hey Coldspeed` which was expected. Next, I tried to apply `partial` to [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
>>> f = partial(isinstance, classinfo=str)
>>> f('hello')
```

But this gave me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() takes no keyword arguments
```

I tried `classinfo` as the argument name since that was what was specified in the docs (linked above). It seems that the actual definition does *not* have the second argument named `classinfo` as the docs might otherwise state.

How now, would I create a partial function with the second parameter without being forced to specify the argname? I definitely cannot do `f = partial(isinstance, str)` because `str` will be taken as the first argument, not the second. If possible, would like to find a way to do this without using `lambda` functions too.

Comment: Just do `f = lambda item: isinstance(item, str)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Trying to avoid `lambdas` completely... :p

Comment: Then write it out longhand with `def`. Same principle: `def f(item): return isinstance(item, str)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hmm, seems like the only other option. Not as pythonic as I'd have hoped but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's just not something `functools.partial` supports. You'd need to write your own version that does support it, or find one in some 3rd-party library somewhere.