# Class to encapsulate args and kwargs

Tags: python

Does something like the following class exist in the Python stdlib (or maybe in some other very common lib)?

```
class Args:
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.args = args
    self.kwargs = kwargs
```

---

## Background

(Although this is just one example, I can imagine that there are more potential use cases.)

I frequently have the pattern that some function forwards the `kwargs` to another, or even some of the `args`.

Examples:

```
class Super: ...

class Foo(Super):
  def __init__(self, foo, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

```
def basic_func(x, opt1, opt2): ...

def higher_level_func(opt3, opt4, **kwargs):
  ...
  y = basic_func(x, **kwargs)
  ...
```

[`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Sometimes when it gets more complex, you see patterns like this:

```
def basic_foo(x, foo1, foo2): ...
def basic_bar(x, bar1, bar2): ...

def higher_level_func(baz1, baz2, foo_opts: Dict[str,Any], bar_opts: Dict[str,Any]):
  ...
  x = basic_foo(x, **foo_opts)
  ...
  x = basic_bar(x, **bar_opts)
  ...
```

I want to generalize `foo_opts: Dict[str,Any]` and `bar_opts: Dict[str,Any]` in this last example to also allow for `args` and not just `kwargs.

You could simply do this:

```
def higher_level_func(baz1, baz2, foo_args: Tuple[Any], foo_kwargs: Dict[str,Any], bar_args: Tuple[Any], bar_kwargs: Dict[str,Any]):
  ...
  x = basic_foo(x, *foo_args, **foo_kwargs)
  ...
  x = basic_bar(x, *bar_args, **bar_kwargs)
  ...
```

But that looks ugly. So I would want to do this instead:

```
def higher_level_func(baz1, baz2, foo_args: Args, bar_args: Args):
  ...
  x = basic_foo(x, *foo_args.args, **foo_args.kwargs)
  ...
  x = basic_bar(x, *bar_args.args, **bar_args.kwargs)
  ...
```

This looks like it would be a useful common pattern, so I wonder whether something like this already exists (maybe even in the stdlib).

Note that `functools.partial` is also already close to what I want. It binds also the function itself (`basic_foo` or `basic_bar` in the example) which is fine. However, the order of the args is different:

```
foo = partial(basic_foo, *args, **kwargs)
...
foo(x) == basic_foo(*args, x, **kwargs)
```

And this is a problem, because I need the `x` arg to be first here, and I would want that the `partial` only binds the following args.
([Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173660/can-one-partially-apply-the-second-argument-of-a-function-that-takes-no-keyword), [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686646/using-functools-partial-with-partial-argument), [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550129/how-to-partially-apply-arbitrary-argument-of-a-function).)

## Bonus question

Somehow tell type checkers like MyPy or PyCharm to what function `Args` matches, e.g. like `Args[basic_foo]`. Not sure if this is feasible...

Comment: I highly doubt this exists in the standard library, because almost all of the time you want to forward both `*args` and `**kwargs`, you want to forward them within the same lexical scope where they're defined, not store them somewhere to be forwarded later from a different scope.

Comment: Perhaps implementing wrapper function is a better solution? Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49376460/10074443

Comment: @kaya3 But in my examples, this is not at all about the scope. It would still forward them within the same lexical scope. It's just some slightly nicer syntax.

Comment: @kklocker: `functools.partial` would be the right candidate for what I want. It would fit almost perfectly, except that the order of the args is wrong. `partial` in this example would do `basic_foo(*foo_args, x, **foo_kwargs)` but not what I have (and need) in the example. Your linked wrapper would not work because it needs to add additional args inside (`x` in the example).